# onReceive doesn't get invoked for BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I tried to register the broadcast receiver in the manifest but the onReceive method isn't invoked. What am I doing wrong?

manifest.xml

```
 <receiver
            android:name="zzz.yyy.xxx.ui.storyboard.discussion.DiscussionFragment$MessageCountReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="zzz.yyy.xxx.ui.storyboard.discussion.GROUPCHAT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Sending broadcast as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("zzz.yyy.xxx.ui.storyboard.discussion.GROUPCHAT");
                intent.putExtra(BundleKeys.notification_post_id_forum,postId);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Receiving broadcast in Fragment class as below:

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        clearUnreadCount();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(messageRefresher);
        super.onPause();
    }


    public class MessageCountReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String noti_post_id = intent.getStringExtra(BundleKeys.notification_post_id_forum);

            int tempCount=PreferencesIMDStar.getIntValue(getActivity(),noti_post_id);
            tempCount++;
            PreferencesIMDStar.setIntValue(getActivity(),noti_post_id,tempCount);


            if (getActivity() != null && noti_post_id.equalsIgnoreCase(post_id)) {
                discussionPresenter.fetchCommentReply(post_id, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you unregistering in `onPause`? Could you be unregistering your own receiver there?

Comment: I notice that `MessageCountReceiver` is an inner class of your Fragment. You may need it to be `static` or define it statically in its own file.